# Finding and replacing HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a string and replace it with another one, but I am facing issue when the string has line breaks/spaces in it

I am trying to find the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ username }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

and replace it with the following:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ salutation }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ username}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

This is my RegEx which apparently isn't working the way I expect it to work

```
<\s*tbody[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*tbody>
```

Comment: Also, could you please show ALL relevant PHP; not just the regex

Comment: Don't use regex for this

Comment: The .* in the regex doesn't match newlines, unless you use the s flag. Could also replace it by [\s\S]* (whitespace or non-whitespace = anything). But yeah, [there's a general understanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) that regex should be the last option for parsing XML/HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it can work in simple cases, you should in general [not use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839) for parsing and modifying HTML. Instead use the DOM interface which is available to PHP via [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

You could use this function:

```
function addSalutation($html) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $tds = $xpath->query('//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),"{{ username }}")]');
    foreach(iterator_to_array($tds) as $td) {
        $newTd = $doc->createElement('td', '{{ salutation }}');
        $newTr = $doc->createElement('tr');
        $newHd = $doc->createElement('thead');

        $newTr->appendChild($newTd);
        $newHd->appendChild($newTr);
        $tbody = $td->parentNode->parentNode;
        $tbody->parentNode->insertBefore($newHd, $tbody);
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Example call:

```
// Sample data
$html = '
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ username }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>';  

// Add salutation
$html = addSalutation($html);

// Output result
echo htmlentities($html);
```

See it run on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/m5NYju)